# Mac - stop Chrome autoupdate

Tags: google-chrome

On Mac, is there a way to stop Chrome from auto-updating itself?

This didn't seem to stop it:

```
$ defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0
```

I also poked into the /Library/Google/ folder to see if I could manually delete any auto-update feature of Chrome, but the "Google" folder was no longer there.

Any other suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Please specify what operating system you are running.

Comment: You've used the correct command according to Google's support doc at: http://support.google.com/installer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=go&answer=147176. Does the setting stick?

Answer (score 0):

`chmod 000 com.google.Keystone.Agent.plist` used to work (it prevented the process from reading the file); but it looks like it will try to delete the unreadable .plist file now.

Combining the above command with an additional ACL:

`chmod +a "everyone deny delete" com.google.Keystone.Agent.plist`

might work.  At least, in my test, it prevented the (re)creation of a readable .plist file.